# How to use a while loop in shell scripting to print on the same line

Tags: bash, shell, printing

Hello i am trying to create a shell script in bash that will print a box with a height and width given by the user. so far my code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
read height
read width
if [ $height -le 2 ];then
echo "error"
fi
if [ $width -le 2 ];then
echo "error"
fi
#this is where i need help
if [ $height -gt 1];then
   if [ $width -gt 1];then
      echo "+"
      counter=$width
      until [ $counter == 0 ]
   do 
      echo "-"
      let counter-=1
   done
fi
fi
```

Currently it will print each "-" on a new line, how do i print them on the same line? Thank you

Comment: Use `printf "%s" "+"` etc to print without a newline.  Or optionally omit the format string since you're only printing a single character.  You'll also need to use loops properly.  It could be `for ((i = 0; i < height; i++); do for ((j = 0; j < width; j++)); do ...; done; printf '\n'; done`

Comment: sorry to clarify my box will be empty on the inside, but with | as the character to make the length part of the box.

Comment: It's a good idea to show what you want as the output in the question — show the input (the height and width you enter) and the corresponding output.  A blank interior makes it easier — you can persuade `printf` to generate spaces.  It is harder to make it produce a different fill character.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `printf` instead:

```
printf "-"
```

---

To pass arguments during running script, using:

```
$./shell-script-name.sh argument1 argument2 argument3
```

Then `argument1`, `argument2` and `argument3` becomes `$1`, `$2` and `$3` respectively inside your shell script.

In your case:

```
#!/bin/bash 
height=$1
width=$2
# ... The rest of the file ...
```

Comment: I agree this is part of the answer.  The code looks like it needs help with the loops too.

Comment: they might i am new to shell scripting and this is our first assignment for it. so far a while loop seemed the best way to do it. also echo -n '-' ended up working as well.

Comment: follow up question, if i wanted the input to be entered in the command line instead of during the script how would i read and assign them height and width? thank you again

Comment: so to clarify if i just put height (newline) width, when launching $./shell-script-name.sh 10 5 this will set height to 10 and width to 5?

Comment: Inside your shell content, you have to assign `height=$1` and then `width=$2` before using `height` and `width`

Comment: one final question for you as my next problem i have to do something similar but it could be any amount of strings after the $./shell-script-name.sh. how would i determine in my shell script how many things were entered. and once again thank you for all the help

Comment: `$#` is the number of all arguments passed.

Comment: pluse uno for tech support ;-) . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Less overhead than `printf` is: `echo -n "-"`

Example:

```
for f in {1..10} ; do echo -n - ; done ; echo
```

Output is 10 hyphens:

```
----------
```